# session not working when i force read html as php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I working at my website for a school project. The web has a login system. I know what I'm doing is dumb, I force read HTML as PHP because my designer team uses HTML for connecting every page and now I don't have more time for editing all of that. But I realize that when I use this command in my .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

the code is for force read HTML as PHP. but when I do that the HTML page that contains PHP inside cant read the session inside. This is the session that I trying to print on the HTML page. The session is set on the login page when the user login. and the code bellow from my home page for a user that successfully login

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "halooo";
echo "The email is " . $_SESSION["email"] . "<br>";
echo "The data is " . $_SESSION["data"] . "<br>";
echo "test dataaaa";
?>
```

That's not the entire code. The other code only for the design and I already try to remove the other code and the session still can't be printed.

I know the best way to do this is to change the HTML to PHP but if there any other solution so I can still force read the HTML to PHP but I also can print the session on the HTML page it will help me a lot. Thank you

This is my login page that where i set the session variable

```
<?php
session_start();



$alert="";
    
    
  include 'config.php';


    if(isset($_POST["login"]))
    {
        $usern = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = md5($_POST['password']);
        

        if($usern && $pass)
        {   
            $sql = "SELECT username, pass, usercode, status FROM client_login WHERE username = '$usern'";
            
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
            {
                $alert= '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                    Data anda tidak ditemukan! Silahkan melakukan Sign Up terlebih dahulu. >> <a href="register.php" class="alert-link">Register</a> <<
                  </div>';

            }else{
                
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 

                if($row["username"] != $usern || $row["pass"] != $pass)
                {
                    $alert= '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                   Username atau Password anda salah! Periksa kembali data anda!
                  </div>';

                }else
                {  
                    $sql2 = "SELECT username, nama, telp, email FROM clientdata WHERE username = '$usern'";
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
                    
                    $_SESSION["username"]=$row["username"] ;
                    $_SESSION["usercode"]=$row["usercode"] ;
                    $_SESSION["email"]=$row2["email"] ;
                    $_SESSION["status"]=$row["status"] ;
                    $_SESSION["session"]= "active";
                    $_SESSION["data"]= "datatest";
                    
                    header('Location : client/home.html');

                }
            }

        }else{
            $alert= '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                    Masukan username dan password!
                  </div>';
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: There is no apparent reason, why this should make any difference. Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? If not, go and do that first of all now, please.

Comment: What do you mean by "cant read the session inside"? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Does the php function on the page, and the only issue is that you are not getting the session information inside the echo?

Comment: how to do proper PHP Error reporting? can you give me specific instructions? Thankyou @NicoHaase

Comment: To do what? Please share more details, like the code that writes such data to the session, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: "cant read the session inside" i mean the php cant print data inside session variable which i set in my login page. Sorry i think i choose wrong word

Comment: Then please share more details, like the code involved to write to the session

Comment: @NicoHaase I updated my question details. There I include my login page. The code everything working file if I don't use the force read HTML as PHP method. But i need that, and wondering is there any solution for that

Comment: Have you checked what `$_SESSION` contains right before the redirect happens? Also, be warned that your SQL queries are widely open for SQL injection - better have a look at prepared statements

Comment: @NicoHaase I already check that. I can confirm that everything is fine. The problem only happened when the session printed in HTML page that forced to read as php

Comment: @RyanH Yes you right, The problem only occurred in the printing SESSION. Other PHP simple and basic command like echo its working

Comment: "Other PHP simple and basic command like echo its working" - If PHP is successfully processing the file then there should be no reason why the _session_ cannot be read. The problem would seem to be unrelated to the file extension? To clarify, if the file has a `.php` extension, does it work?

Comment: if i change the file extension to .php the session is working @MrWhite

Answer (score 2):

So `AddType` inside your .htaccess is setting the MIME type to transmit to the client when sending a `.html` file.  This is ***NOT*** configuring apache to `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php`.  Depending on your hosts configuration you may not be able actually set this at the .htaccess level.
To parse .html files with the php interpreter you would need something similar to the following.  Please read through the documentation for your use case.

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.html$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Hello there. Thank you for helping. But I try your .htaccess configuration and there the session still not printing.

Comment: You may not be able to set this in the .htaccess, this will depend on what your host has allowed for overrides from the server configuration.  You need to find out from your provers documentation to see if the SetHander is an allowed override. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#sethandler and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride are good starting point for the apache documentation but few providers would just have set AllowOverride set to ALL and the default for apache is set to NONE

Comment: i already try to configure directly from Cpanel apache handler and the handler is working i can use basic php command, but still the problem is it still failed to print data from Session variable

Comment: If you change the file to a .php file does it work?  If not I would check your php.ini settings file for the web server

Comment: yes if i change the file extension to .php its working

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is that you and the login page might be configured on different version of php .... if you can get ahold of the config for the running apache instance check what the SetHandler is set to for the php files it is possible that it is set to something like `application/x-httpd-php7.2` (or even something completely different)

Answer (score 0):

> because my designer team uses HTML for connecting every page and now I don't have more time for editing all of that

An alternative solution/workaround... maintain all the internal links to `.html` URLs, but rename the underlying files to `.php` (which presumably "work") and *internally rewrite* the URL using Apache's mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` from `.html` to `.php`. This avoids having to rename all the `.html` links made by the "designer team".

For example, the internal links are to `/about.html` and `/foo/bar.html`, but the underlying files are `/about.php` and `/foo/bar.php` respectively. Then, in your `.htaccess` file rewrite from `.html` to `.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite .html requests to .php
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

The above rule is unconditional, it rewrites all `.html` requests, regardless of whether or not the target `.php` files exists. This is not usually a problem, as you simply get the 404 on the `.php` instead of the `.html`. Any `.html` files are not going to be accessible.

If you specifically want to check that the target `.php` exists before rewriting then change the above rule to the following:

```
# Rewrite .html requests to .php - if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

This allows `.html` files to be accessible, but if the same file exists as both `.html` and `.php` then the `.php` file takes priority.